# The value is returned instead of NULL when using function with OUTER APPLY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, apply, outer-apply

I am getting strange results when using inline function. Here is the code:

```
IF EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM sys.objects AS o WHERE name = 'vendor_relation_users'
) DROP FUNCTION dbo.vendor_relation_users;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[vendor_relation_users]
(
    @user_name CHAR(12)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN (SELECT @user_name AS user_name WHERE @user_name NOT LIKE '06%');
GO

DECLARE @u CHAR(12) = '066BDLER'
SELECT a.user_name, is_v.user_name 
FROM (SELECT @u AS user_name) a
OUTER APPLY [dbo].[vendor_relation_users](@u) AS is_v

SELECT a.user_name, is_v.user_name 
FROM (SELECT @u AS user_name) a
OUTER APPLY (SELECT @u AS user_name WHERE @u NOT LIKE '06%') AS is_v


SELECT * FROM [dbo].[vendor_relation_users](@u)
```

[image]

So in the first SELECT statement I've just OUTER APPLied the function and it returns the result.

In the next statement I've took the code from function and put it straight to the OUTER APPLY statement.

And the last statement is just the direct function call.

**I can't get why do the FIRST query returns the value...**

Comment: What you think will return the second query? `@u NOT LIKE '06%'` return false so you get `NULL`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza exactly and NULL is expected result

Comment: So the wrong result should be the first one? not the second one.

Comment: Modified the question to make it more clear

Comment: That make it clear, but then your title doesnt match your question :P

Comment: @SeanLange That is the question If there isnt a row, how the first outer apply return a value?

Comment: It returned the variable value. I've tried to hardcode string to the output of the function and it returned NULL as expected, but in that case it is returning the value of variable. Sounds like a bug...

Comment: @SeanLange Can you elaborate on Why? The first column is an scalar but the second return an empty set and still have same value as the scalar

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I was not getting the question. I see the challenge now. :)

Comment: Here is a weird one.....I changed the variable name inside the function to @u and it worked perfectly. I suspect there is a bug in there somewhere because changing the name would have caused a recompile. I then set the name back and it continued to work perfectly.

Comment: And now I can't recreate this on another database. Quite strange indeed.

Comment: Might be the same basic issue as here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32414450/73226

Comment: A work around might be to use `OUTER APPLY (select * from [dbo].[vendor_relation_users](@u)) AS is_v` as that seems to avoid the issue.

Answer (score 11):

This is a very interesting query. The behaviour of your first query depends upon whether you use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` or not.

As you point out, this:

```
DECLARE @u CHAR(12) = '066BDLER'
SELECT a.user_name, is_v.user_name 
FROM (SELECT @u AS user_name) a
OUTER APPLY [dbo].[vendor_relation_users](@u) AS is_v
```

returns this:

```
user_name       user_name
066BDLER        066BDLER
```

but if you add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` like this:

```
SELECT a.user_name, is_v.user_name 
FROM (SELECT @u AS user_name) a
OUTER APPLY [dbo].[vendor_relation_users](@u) AS is_v
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

you correctly get this:

```
user_name       user_name
066BDLER        NULL
```

I suspect this is due to a bug in how the query optimiser short circuits these inline functions due to cardinality estimates. If you look at the query plan for the two queries you will see that the one without the OPTION RECOMPILE just returns a constant.

Comment: Exactly! First query just shows a Constant Scan while the last query shows a Constant Scan and a Filter while the second query is much more complicated in query plan. After adding the recompile the query plans of the first and second query nearly match.

Answer (score 6):

I guess it is old bug described [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/725323/outer-apply-returns-incorrect-results). And it is `Closed as Won't Fix`

Please use this function like:

```
SELECT a.user_name, is_v.user_name 
FROM (SELECT @u AS user_name) a
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[vendor_relation_users](a.user_name) 
    ) AS is_v
```

**UPDATE#1**

Just read the comments:

> Might be the same basic issue as here [stackoverflow.com/a/32414450/73226](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32414450/73226) – Martin Smith

That is it! Same issue, same link I have provided to MS Connect site.

**UPDATE#2**

Instead:

```
RETURN (SELECT @user_name AS user_name WHERE @user_name NOT LIKE '06%');
```

You need to use:

```
RETURN (SELECT CASE WHEN @user_name LIKE '06%' THEN NULL ELSE @user_name END)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[vendor_relation_users]
(
    @user_name CHAR(12)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN (SELECT CASE WHEN @user_name NOT LIKE '06%' THEN  @user_name  ELSE NULL END as [user_name]);  
GO
```

Ok,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql

> If the SELECT statement returns no rows, the variable retains its
>   present value. If expression is a scalar subquery that returns no
>   value, the variable is set to NULL.

For example

```
DECLARE @u CHAR(12) = '066BDLER'
SELECT  @u  = 'AAAA' WHERE 1 <> 1
SELECT @u
```

Under any conditions, the value of the SELECT @variable will not change, and DB ENGINE simplifies the statement to

> |--Constant Scan

If use RECOMPILE sql build new plan with condition and plan change

> ```
>         |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1001]='066BDLER    '))
>              |--Filter(WHERE:(STARTUP EXPR(NOT '066BDLER    ' like '06%')))
>                   |--Constant Scan
> ```

But RECOMPILE requires compilation costs, then use CASE for return

ps 
If you do not change the function, then you can bypass the assignment, otherwise why would you ever APPLY :)

```
DECLARE @u CHAR(12) = '066BDLER'
SELECT a.user_name, is_v.user_name 
FROM (SELECT @u AS user_name) a
OUTER APPLY [dbo].[vendor_relation_users](a.user_name) AS is_v
```

Comment: "If the SELECT statement returns no rows, the variable retains its present value" is it documented statement or just the opinion?